# Как запускать асинхронный метод периодически

Tags: c#

сделал метод, который проверяет доступен сайт или нет, метод асинхронный, Теперь встал вопрос а как такой метод правильно запускать периодически через промежуток времени. Хотел просто использовать цикл while(true), но это не верно.
Вот сам метод.

```
 class Me
{
    // проверяем доступен ли ресурс для парсинга.
    public async Task<bool> GoodUrl()
    {
        string url = "https://www.rabota66.ru";
        bool rezult = true;
        try
        {
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
            httpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            httpWebRequest.Referer = "http://google.com"; // Реферер. Тут можно указать любой URL
            if (await httpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync() is HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse &&
                httpWebResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                rezult = true;
            }
            else
            {
                rezult = false;
            }

            return rezult;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ресурс не доступен" + e);
            throw;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
         var me=new Me();
            while (true)
            {
               Task.Delay(1000);
                var rz = me.GoodUrl();
                 Console.WriteLine(rz.Result);

             }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавь просто задержу перед следующей итерацией цикла через `await Task.Delay(1000)` и следующий запрос к сайту произойдет через 1 секунду.

Comment: `цикл while(true), но это не верно` - почему же? Вполне даже хорошее решение. Добавляете задержку, добавляете CancelationToken и вперед!

Comment: @adrug При такой реализации просто нужна задержка? Сейчас у меня почему то только два раза выводится true

Comment: В текущем варианте после выбрасывания исключения ваш цикл завершит работу. Задержка в цикле `whilt(true)` в совокупности с `await Task.Delay(1000)` даст вам эффект периодического запуска.

Comment: @adrug Подправил вопрос, только мне нужно что бы версия .net была  4,5  и с await ошибка идет

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Допустим, у нас есть асинхронный метод для проверки вебсайта

```
async Task<bool> CheckWebsite()
{
    // эмуляция проверки вашего сайта
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    return true;
}
```

Далее, нам нужен цикл, где мы будем проверять наш вебсайт. Цикл будет работать так: если проверка сайта занимает меньше секунды. то мы запускаем проверку строго раз в секунду. Если проверка занимает больше секунды - то мы ждем конца проверки и сразу запускаем следующую. То есть если проверка сайта займет 0.1 секунды - то мы запкускаем её раз в секунду. Если проверка сайта занимает 3 секунды - то запускаем проверку раз в 3 секунды. Это сделано так как нет смысла запускать следующую проверку, если предыдущая ещё не закончилась.

```
async Task TimerCheck(CancellationToken token)
{
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var delay = Task.Delay(1000);
        var ret = CheckWebsite();
        await Task.WhenAll(delay, ret);
        Console.WriteLine($"Site check returns {ret.Result}");
    }
}
```

Далее, метод Main может и не быть асинхронным. Я сделал следующее: создает токен для возможности отмены операции, потом запускаем операцию, потом ждем юзера - он когда захочет - прервет цикл.

```
void Main()
{
    var ts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var cycleTask = TimerCheck(ts.Token);
    Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit");
    Console.ReadLine();
    ts.Cancel();
    cycleTask.Wait();
}
```

Вывод ожидаемо:

```
Press enter to exit
Site check returns True
Site check returns True
Site check returns True
Site check returns True
Site check returns True
Site check returns True
Site check returns True
```

Comment: Спасибо, меня как раз и смущал тот факт, что время проверки то разное может быть. Спасибо за ответ..

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch ну у вас 2 варианта - либо запускать параллельные проверки, либо нет. Я предпочитаю не запускать, проще таймаут адекватный выставить при выполнении запроса. Абсолютно того же самого эффекта можно добиться через таймер, но там код будет чуточку сложнее

Comment: Да я про таймер читал, там сложнее и длиннее.