# Как организовать рассылку нескольких тысяч http запросов каждые N секунд в .NET Core?

Tags: c#, cron, .net-core, очередь, rabbitmq

Моя система должна будет каждые, например, 60 секунд отправлять много http запросов. Это рассылка пуш уведомлений с помощью FCM Cloud Messaging. Вот [документация](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref). Я не особо опытный .NET разработчик. Хочу поинтересоваться у людей, имевших опыт реализации бекграундовых задач с рассылкой, как лучше это сделать. Я пробовал такой код:

```
public class Example
{
    private static Timer aTimer;

    public static void Main()
    {
        // Create a timer and set a two second interval.
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        aTimer.Interval = 2000;

        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
        aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;

        // Have the timer fire repeated events (true is the default)
        aTimer.AutoReset = true;

        // Start the timer
        aTimer.Enabled = true;

        Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to exit the program at any time... ");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0}", e.SignalTime);
    }
}
```

Это пример из официальной документации майкрософт по классу `System.Timers`. Поначалу мне показалось, что он подходит идеально. Поскольку у меня к реализации были требования, запускать и останавливать рассылку из веба (контроллер MVC), выводить на вьюху идет ли рассылка, использовать DI. Но потом я столкнулся с проблемой. Если одна задача не успела закончиться, а другая начинается, то система падает. Падает не просто задача, а вообще все, в том числе и MVC.

Потом я подумал, а может сделать вот как. Каждую минуту происходит выборка пользователей на пуш. Все они добавляются в некую очередь (может rebbitMQ). А очередь эта работает так, как сможет. Я имею в виду, в своем темпе трудится или простаивает, если задач на пуш не пришло. Я пользователей повторно не пушу каждые 10 секунд, так что рано или поздно эта очередь начнет работать в лайтовом режиме. Но иногда ей придется потрудиться. Это та схема, которая мне видится в голове. То есть, финализирую. Каждые 60 секунд запускается выборка пользователей на пуш, пользователи добавляются в некую очередь, которая в своем темпе рассылает пуши, пока есть задачи. Тут и вопросы возникают:

- Жизнеспособно ли это?
- Пойдет ли обычный таймер для записи задач на пуш в очередь? Или использовать крон с консольным приложением?
- Или может есть какой то готовый scheduler под такие задачи и моя схема с добавлением задач на пуш в очередь и рассылкой - оверинженеринг?

Я пробовал такой scheduler https://github.com/fluentscheduler/FluentScheduler. У него очень странный DI. Там все как то на статических методах. Пробовал  [Hosted services](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio). Но я не понял, как остановить или запустить такой сервис из веба методы Start и Stop работают странно. Я по этому поводу задавал вопрос [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58290902/why-do-we-need-hostedservices-if-we-have-ordinary-system-timers).

В общем прошу поделиться опытом тех людей, кто решал что то подобное. Заранее огромное спасибо!

#### UPDATE

Итак, благодаря комментариям пользователя @tym32167 я пришел к решению просто дождаться когда на определенной итерации моего таймера метод с работой завершится. Для этого, в начале этого метода я остановлю таймер, а когда он завершиться, запущу снова. Вот код:

```
public class Scheduler
{
    private const int MSecond = 1000;
    private readonly int _seconds = MSecond * 10;
    private Timer _aTimer;

    public void Start()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sending is started ...");

        _aTimer = new Timer();
        _aTimer.Interval = _seconds;

        _aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;

        _aTimer.AutoReset = true;

        _aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    public bool IsWorking()
    {
        return _aTimer != null;
    }

    private async void OnTimedEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        await JustDoIt();
    }

    private async Task JustDoIt()
    {
        _aTimer.Stop();

        // большая и трудная работа 
        await Task.Delay(1000 * 12);
        Console.WriteLine("Done !!");

        _aTimer.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _aTimer.Stop();
        _aTimer = null;
    }
}
```

Это эмуляция реальной задачи, поскольку он просто ждет и печатает в консоль "Done". При этом, заметьте, я пытаюсь эмулировать ситуацию, когда метод работает дольше, чем таймер. Таймр в примере работает 10 секунд, а метод 12. Если бы одновременно, запустилась бы параллельная задача с выполнением этого же метода, то, возможно, они могли бы испортить данные в базе, поскольку в моем реальном проекте, этот метод пишет в базу и читает. 
А то что реализованно в этом коде работает так. Сначала запускается таймер, выполняется метод с работой. В начале метода таймер выключается, дальше выполняется код (чтение, запись в базу), таймер включается, работаем дальше в бесконечном цикле. Все ли корректно в этом классе?

Comment: не понятно, вам надо хранить ваши задачи где то? Или вам надо запускать таймер так, чтобы следующий запуск ждал предыдущего? Или вам надо просто много запросов отправить? Вы определитесь, что вам сделать надо, а то вас бросает с таймера на какие то внешние системы типа раббита.

Comment: @tym32167 Мне желательно сохранить информацию о том, что такой то пользователь получил такой то пуш. Причем FCM отправляет ответ и из ответа можно понят, дошел ли пуш. Иногда бывает `success: 0`. Такой json там можно найти. Вариант, чтоб следующий запуск гарантированно дождался предыдущего - это то что надо.

Comment: Ну сохраняйте информацию о том, что было выслано и какой пришел ответ в логи или в БД или куда вам удобней. Вариантов синхронизации запусков есть несколько. Например, можно сделать таймер одноразовым и продлевать его в событии таймера. Или всё внутри события таймера в lock завернуть.  Но мне, например, больше нравится [асинхронный цикл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/895576/179763)

Comment: Сообщения отсылаются одинаковые или разные?

Comment: Сообщения отсылаются разные, но могут повторяться.

Comment: @tym32167 По поводу сделать лок внутри таймера. Это позволит не начинаться новому процессу, когда ресурс занят? По поводу продления таймера, вам не сложно было бы привести пример, как именно это можно сделать? По поводу асинхронного цикла, я посмотрел, этот вариант выглядит неплохо. Нужно будет написать консольное приложение, которое занимается рассылкой. Стартовать и останавливать его я смог бы из веба, если бы сделал в БД соответствующую таблицу с настройками, где был бы флаг старт/стоп. Другого способа запуска такого цикла я не вижу.

Comment: lock - это синхронизаия между потоками,  а не процессами. Если вам надо синхронизировать между процессами, то вам понадобится мьютекс или семафор. По поаоду продления таймера- 1) запускаете таймер. 2) В событии таймера маймер останавливаете 3) Как сделали что вам надо, снова запускаете таймер. И так по кругу

Comment: Асинхронный цикл вы можете запускать хоть из веб приложения, хоть из консоли, циклу это асболютно не важно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант с таймером может выглядеть вот так

```
public class Scheduler
{
    private const int TimerIntervalInSeconds = 10;
    private Timer _aTimer;

    public void Start()
    {
        Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Sending is started ...");
        _aTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(OnTimedEvent, 
            null, TimeSpan.Zero, 
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TimerIntervalInSeconds));
    }

    public bool IsWorking => _aTimer != null;   

    private async void OnTimedEvent(object state)
    {
        var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var next = now.AddSeconds(TimerIntervalInSeconds);
        _aTimer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);        
        try
        {           
            await JustDoIt();
        }
        finally
        {
            var diff = next - DateTime.UtcNow;          
            if (diff.TotalMilliseconds > 0){
                _aTimer?.Change(diff, 
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TimerIntervalInSeconds));
            }
            else {
                OnTimedEvent(state);
            }
        }
    }

    private Random r = new Random();
    private async Task JustDoIt()
    {
        var wait = r.Next(25);
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} Waiting for next {wait} seconds !!");        
        // большая и трудная работа 
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(wait));
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} Done !!");       
    }

    public void Stop()
    {       
        _aTimer?.Dispose();
        _aTimer = null;
    }
}
```

Я дорбавил немного случайности, чтобы некоторые задачи длились дольше 10 секунд, некоторые нет.

Также сама работа помещена в tfy-finally, так как мы не хотим прерывать работу, если текущая задача провалилась. Добавьте там catch по вкусу, если вам это необходимо.

Ну и я использовал другой таймер - System.Threading.Timer, он, как мне кажется, по легче да и с ним мне прозе работать. Хотя ваш вариант тоже ничего, если сделать `_aTimer.AutoReset = false;`

Как проверить таймер:

```
var scheduler = new Scheduler();
scheduler.Start();
Console.ReadLine();
scheduler.Stop();
```

Вывод

```
Sending is started...
12.10.2019 19:32:02 Waiting for next 17 seconds !!
12.10.2019 19:32:19 Done !!
12.10.2019 19:32:19 Waiting for next 5 seconds !!
12.10.2019 19:32:24 Done !!
12.10.2019 19:32:29 Waiting for next 16 seconds !!
12.10.2019 19:32:45 Done !!
12.10.2019 19:32:45 Waiting for next 11 seconds !!
12.10.2019 19:32:56 Done !!
12.10.2019 19:32:56 Waiting for next 21 seconds !!
12.10.2019 19:33:17 Done !!
12.10.2019 19:33:17 Waiting for next 12 seconds !!
12.10.2019 19:33:29 Done !!
12.10.2019 19:33:29 Waiting for next 3 seconds !!
12.10.2019 19:33:32 Done !!
12.10.2019 19:33:39 Waiting for next 18 seconds !!
12.10.2019 19:33:57 Done !!
12.10.2019 19:33:57 Waiting for next 12 seconds !!
12.10.2019 19:34:09 Done !!
12.10.2019 19:34:09 Waiting for next 6 seconds !!
12.10.2019 19:34:15 Done !!
```

Второй вариант с асинхронным цмклом (который мне больше нравится)

```
public class Scheduler
{
    private const int TimerIntervalInSeconds = 10;  
    private CancellationTokenSource _cancelTokenSource;

    public void Start()
    {
        Stop();
        _cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Console.WriteLine("Sending is started ...");        
        MainCycle(_cancelTokenSource.Token);
    }

    public bool IsWorking => _cancelTokenSource != null;

    async Task MainCycle(CancellationToken token)
    {
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var nextTime = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TimerIntervalInSeconds));            
            try
            {           
                await Task.WhenAll(nextTime, JustDoIt());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                /// log errors          
            }
        }
    }

    private Random r = new Random();
    private async Task JustDoIt()
    {
        var wait = 5 + r.Next(25);
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} Waiting for next {wait} seconds !!");
        // большая и трудная работа 
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(wait));
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} Done !!");
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _cancelTokenSource?.Cancel();
        _cancelTokenSource = null;
    }
}
```

Принцип работы примерно тот же самый, проверить можно точно также

```
var scheduler = new Scheduler();
scheduler.Start();
Console.ReadLine();
scheduler.Stop();
```

Вывод

```
Sending is started ...
12.10.2019 19:32:47 Waiting for next 16 seconds !!
12.10.2019 19:33:03 Done !!
12.10.2019 19:33:03 Waiting for next 26 seconds !!
12.10.2019 19:33:29 Done !!
12.10.2019 19:33:29 Waiting for next 24 seconds !!
12.10.2019 19:33:53 Done !!
12.10.2019 19:33:53 Waiting for next 9 seconds !!
12.10.2019 19:34:02 Done !!
12.10.2019 19:34:03 Waiting for next 23 seconds !!
12.10.2019 19:34:26 Done !!
12.10.2019 19:34:26 Waiting for next 22 seconds !!
12.10.2019 19:34:48 Done !!
12.10.2019 19:34:48 Waiting for next 27 seconds !!
12.10.2019 19:35:15 Done !!
12.10.2019 19:35:15 Waiting for next 15 seconds !!
12.10.2019 19:35:30 Done !!
12.10.2019 19:35:30 Waiting for next 7 seconds !!
12.10.2019 19:35:37 Done !!
12.10.2019 19:35:40 Waiting for next 9 seconds !!
12.10.2019 19:35:49 Done !!
12.10.2019 19:35:50 Waiting for next 23 seconds !!
```

Смотрите тайминги, проверяйте, что вам больше подходит.

Comment: @Aleksej_Shherbak на здоровье